How to create Google Analytics user path report with all the paths (or at least a few of them) to key events?
Is there any way to set up a report that will automatically have all expanded paths like:

Session start -> page click -> other page click -> key event
Session start -> page click -> other key event

etc.?
You can find these out manually by starting at the key events and then expanding step by step towards the beginning. Is there a way to fully automate this though? Even if only for a few limited full paths at one time.
